# Use Property as factory-method in Spring.Net

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net

Is there a way to use a static property of a class as the factory-method for a object definition?

```
  <object id="MyObject" type="MyNamespace.Factory, MyAssembly" factory-method="FactoryObject"  /> 
  <!-- "FactoryObject" is a Property (with getter) of the class "Factory" -->
```

Using this config a exception is thrown:

Error creating context 'spring.root': Cannot find matching factory method 'FactoryObject on Type [MyNamespace.Factory]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unconventional, but you can use a property if you use the generated get method by the compiler.

```
<object id="MyObject" type="MyNamespace.Factory, MyAssembly" factory-method="get_FactoryObject"  />
```